# Using select by location is a stand alone script

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-script-tool, select-by-location, error-000368

I have script that I run quite regularly in the python window of Arcmap 10.2.2 and am in the process of converting it to a toolbox script so that others can use it more easily.

It uses select layer by location a number of times, for example:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(Contours_G_1m, "CONTAINS", peakpoints)
```

It worked fine in the python window but now that its in a tool it fails with

> Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000368: Invalid input data

This is not at all surprising because this tool works on a layer and the script does not add a layer to the map when it creates a new feature class.

Is there any way of selecting the feature in a shapefile rather than a layer by location, or a workaround for using this tool in a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the input data of selectlayerbylocation is a **layer**. When you take it from ArcGIS python Windows, the feature class is already accessed through a layer, but with a stand alone script it is necessary to create the layer first.

This can be done with [MakeFeatureLayer_management (in_features, out_layer, {where_clause}, {workspace}, {field_info})](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-feature-layer.htm)